# How to only fire Window.Closing event on certain conditions?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've searched my way and it seems I don't find a definitve answer to that question or I overread every single one of them.
Im reading in commandline arguments and one of them determines if the last window state should be saved or not. If the user entered the argument I subscribed the closing event to my MainWindow.

In another class:

```
if(saveSettings.Equals("Sw") || saveSettings.Equals("SW") || saveSettings.Equals("sw"))
{
    Main.Closing += Main.Window_Closing_1;
}
```

the event:

```
public void Window_Closing_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{

    SaveWindowState newWindowwState = new SaveWindowState();

    newWindowwState.WindowHeight = this.Height;
    newWindowwState.WindowWidth = this.Width;
    newWindowwState.WindowTop = this.Top;
    newWindowwState.WindowLeft = this.Left;
    newWindowwState.State = this.WindowState;

    newWindowwState.Save();
```

How do I make sure this event is only executed when above conditions were met? Im relativly new to wpf so my knowledge of events is rather weak.

Comment: Why don't you simply check the condition in Closing?

Comment: The event handler will only be executed when you had attached it to the event before. Besides that, the three string comparisons are redundant. Just call `saveSettings.Equals("sw", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Clemens: To be pedantic. That would allow "sW" and it isn't in his current code.

Comment: @Ralf That's certainly true... And it's probably "her" code. Better "their".

Comment: You can simply unsubscribe after first call. But I dislike idea of subscribing, rather use `bool` property which is reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "How to only fire Window.Closing event on certain conditions?"

Only the event source can control how to raise events. Outside this class you can only *handle* events.
In your case, `Window.Closing` will be raised only once when the `Window` is about to close. You can handle it by registering an event handler e.g., `Window_Closing_1` or ignore it by not registering or unregistering an event handler. But the event will be raised regardless of your choice.

> "How do I make sure this event is only executed when above conditions
> were met?"

As explained before, you cannot control when or if the *event* is raised. But you can control whether your *event handler* (callback) will be invoked or not.

Your current code already does what you want, given that the condition won't change during runtime: you are currently only listening to the `Closing` event, when the condition evaluates to `true`. Because only then you register the `Window_Closing_1` event handler.

Another solution would be to always listen to the event and decide inside the event handler whether to execute the handler or not. This is especially useful when the condition can change during runtime:

```
public Constructor()
{
    Main.Closing += Main.Window_Closing_1;
}

public void Window_Closing_1(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!saveSettings.Equals("sw", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Condition failed --> don't handle
        return;
    }


    SaveWindowState newWindowwState = new SaveWindowState();

    newWindowwState.WindowHeight = this.Height;
    newWindowwState.WindowWidth = this.Width;
    newWindowwState.WindowTop = this.Top;
    newWindowwState.WindowLeft = this.Left;
    newWindowwState.State = this.WindowState;

    newWindowwState.Save();
}
```

As long as the condition is static, both versions are equally "good". I recommend this read: [Microsoft Docs: Handling and raising events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Got a better understanding of events and handling them !